# Calculating height of a logical expression

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, predicate, ocaml-dune

I have a task of calculating the height of a logical expression (like a∧(b∨c)). I have an algorithm, however there is a mistake that causes 2 errors

1. this function application is partial
2. This expression has type int * int -> int * int
   but an expression was expected of type int
   I have no clue what I'm doing wrong? Below is the code snippet:

   ```
   let height f g = 
       let rec aux acc = function
           | Bot -> acc+1
           | Top -> acc+1
           | Atome x -> acc+1
           | Imp(f, g) -> max(aux(acc+1)f, aux(acc+1)g)
           | And(f, g) -> max(aux(acc+1)f, aux(acc+1)g)
           | Or(f, g) -> max(aux(acc+1)f, aux(acc+1)g)
       in
       acc 0;;
   ```

Thank's a lot in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `in aux 0` rather than `in acc 0`?

Comment: the comma is the tuple constructor, but `max` does not work on tuples

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you're passing a tuple to `max` rather than two curried arguments.

```
let height f g = 
  let rec aux acc = function
    | Bot -> acc+1
    | Top -> acc+1
    | Atome x -> acc+1
    | Imp (f, g) -> max (aux (acc+1) f) (aux (acc+1) g)
    | And (f, g) -> max (aux (acc+1) f) (aux (acc+1) g)
    | Or (f, g) -> max (aux (acc+1) f) (aux (acc+1) g)
  in
  acc 0
```

While you *can* write functions that take multiple arguments as a single tuple, this is not idiomatic in OCaml.

```
let f x y = ...
```

Vs.

```
let f (x, y) = ...
```